# jQuery. Changing images on click

Tags: jquery

I am needing to use jQuery that enables a user to click through a series of portfolio images on my website. Basic "next" image functionality.

```
<div class="dis_flex" id="estate_gallery">
 <div class="dis_flex" id="estate_photos">
  <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Real Estate image 1"/>  
 </div><!-- end estate_photo -->
</div><!-- end estate_gallery -->
```

So essentially I have '1.jpg' visible on site entrance. When '1.jpg' is clicked '2.jpg' takes it place, when '2.jpg' is clicked '3.jpg' takes its place and so on.

Here is what I have with my very limited knowledge

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#estate_photos').click(function() {
$('img').attr('src', 'images/2.jpg');
});});
```

So I can swap the 'src' attribute but how can I make jQuery "add 1" to the *.jpg number each time I click.

I'm positive this is not the correct way to go about this at all so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#estate_photos').click(function() {


                var lastImage=$('#estate_photos').children().last();

                var lastSrc=lastImage.attr('src');

                var lastNumberPart=lastSrc.split('.')[0];

                var lastNumber=lastNumberPart.substr(lastNumberPart.length-1,lastNumberPart.length);



                 var increamented=parseInt(lastNumber)+1;
                $('img').attr('src', 'images/'+increamented+'.jpg');


            });


            });
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked as desired. Very Grateful. Out of interest how what would one do to get back to 1.jpg once the last image is click (10.jpg). How would i a user get back to the start of all the images without refreshing the page? I assume some sort of IF statement may work??

Comment: If image count or last number is known like 10 or 20 , then check if(lastNumber=='10'){var increamented=1 }

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="dis_flex" id="estate_gallery">
 <div class="dis_flex" id="estate_photos">
  <img id="carousel1" src="images/1.jpg" alt="Real Estate image 1" data-id="1"/>  
 </div><!-- end estate_photo -->
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#estate_photos').click(function() {
    var count = $('img').attr("data-id") + 1;
    $('#carousel1').attr("data-id", count);
    $('#carousel1').attr('src', 'images/' + count + '.jpg');
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this did not seem to work. When i clicked on the image it just displayed the "alt" attribute.